# Extract "alert" text from push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have the following code placed in my app delegate file. In theory, it should be extracting the message from the push notification and displaying it in a `UIAlertview` - yet it displays the title and the candle button, and nothing else. Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    pushText = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"News", "")
                          message:pushText
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: if you try debug the code, you get the right value in pushText?

Comment: No it is coming up as `null`

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. The userInfo dict handles any key-value pairs from the sender, are you extracting the correct key from the dictionary? I believe in parse you can send a custom userinfo dict as a parameter when sending a push, so if you define @"customBodyText":@"this is my message" for example, make sure when you read the notification (receive it), you read the @"customBodyText" key.

Comment: If you output the userInfo in the first line of this method, what is the actual string that you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The push payload has the following structure:

```
{
    "aps" : {
             "alert" : "Push notification text"
             }
}
```

So you need to pull out the "aps" dictionary first and then you can retrieve the value for the "alert" key:

```
 pushText = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
```