# swift solution for extracting message from parse push notification

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

the code below can be found from the thread (link below), i cannot seem to translate this into a swift solution because the code's flaw doesn't seem to be an intuitive fix in swift (at least from my understanding)...

could someone please help to translate this code, I need the ability to read the message from a parse push notification in swift (which I believe this code to do in objective c)

[Extract "alert" text from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115054/extract-alert-text-from-push-notification)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
pushText = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"News", "")
                      message:pushText
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

}

Comment: There is no substitute for first reading the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your AppDelegate...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if let pushText = userInfo["alert"] as? String {
        let title = NSLocalizedString("News",comment:"")
        let alert = UIAlertView(title, message: pushText, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```